# Is there an option to generate a report in Jira to show all of the backups?

Tags: linux, cron, jira

I have a cron job that is set up to backup the system every day at low-traffic hours. However, I need a monthly report to show at which time the backup was created and if it was successfull. Could anyone help me with that?